# Count after joining two tables

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have the following tables:

**appointment**

```
id |    date    |   time
1  | 2018-12-02 | 10:00:00
2  | 2018-12-05 | 12:00:00
3  | 2018-12-12 | 16:00:00
4  | 2018-12-12 | 17:00:00
5  | 2018-12-13 | 09:00:00
```

**appointment_services**

```
id | appointment_id | service_id
1  |        1       |     24
2  |        2       |     24
3  |        3       |     21
4  |        4       |     24
5  |        5       |     18
```

I would like to search for a date period from appointment table and count for each service_id from appointment_services table.

So the end result will be

```
service_id | times
     24    |   3
     21    |   1
     18    |   1
```

This is what I have done so far

```
SELECT * FROM `appointment` a
INNER JOIN appointment_services s ON a.id = s.appointment_id
WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2018-12-10' AND '2018-12-18'
```

Comment: Store dates and times as a single entity

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
select s.service_id, count(*) as times
from appointment_services s
join appintment a on a.id = s.appointment_id
where a.date between '2018-12-10' and '2018-12-18'
group by s.service_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using count() aggregation and group by

```
 SELECT s.service_id, count(*) as cnttimes
    FROM `appointment` a
    INNER JOIN appointment_services s ON a.id = s.appointment_id
    WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2018-12-10' AND '2018-12-18'
    group by s.service_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You must group data by service_id column with help [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-modifiers.html) statement. For example:

```
SELECT s.service_id, 
       count(*) as times
FROM `appointment` a
INNER JOIN appointment_services s ON a.id = s.appointment_id
WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2018-12-10' AND '2018-12-18'
GROUP BY s.service_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend left joining the `appointment_services` table to a subquery on `appointment` with a restriction to the date range you want.  This will allow us to retain all service values even if there be no matching appointments.

```
SELECT
    s.service_id,
    COUNT(a.id) AS times
FROM appointment_services s
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM appointment
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-12-10' AND '2018-12-18'
) a
    ON s.appointment_id = a.id
GROUP BY
    s.service_id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that I intentionally changed the data for `service_id = 18` such that its single appointment does *not* fall within your desired date range.  Using the approach I suggest, we still report `18` with a zero count.  Doing a straight inner join would have filtered off `18` entirely, and it would appear in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ad0f03/1

```
SELECT s.service_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM `appointment_services` s
LEFT JOIN  appointment a 
ON a.id = s.appointment_id
WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2018-12-10' AND '2018-12-18'
GROUP BY s.service_id
```

The problem with your expected result is your `WHERE` clause which cut few recods, so valid result is:

```
service_id COUNT(*)
18          1
21          1
24          1
```